# Ejecutar archivo PHP desde JS cada minuto

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Buenas necesitó ejecutar un archivo PHP cada cierto tiempo en este caso cada minuto, solo ejecutar el archivo sin abrir otra ventana en navegador

solo tengo esto

```
setInterval(function(){ "Ejecutar archivo php" }, 1000 * 10);
```

pero no se que hacer para ejecutar el archivo

Comment: para estas cosas se suelen crear ***cron jobs*** en el servidor, si vas a dejar el navegador abierto para hacer esto: puedes hacer una petición cada cierto tiempo, p.e. enviar un formulario, al recibirlo la app php ejecutara la tarea y cargará la página con el formulario, se inicia la cuenta atrás...

Comment: justo quería usar cron jobs pero no tengo permitido usarlo

Comment: la idea del `setInterval` es buena y puede funcionar perfectamente, el problema debe estar en tu función  que ejecuta el archivo php

Comment: Asumiendo que tu archivo JS lo usas en el cliente... ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer? ¿Cuál es tu problemática? o mejor dicho ¿Cuál es el escenario donde lo aplicarías? A lo largo de mi experiencia encontré muchos casos en los que planteaban la misma idea, pero era porque tomaban el camino equivocado para solucionarlo, tal vez por la confusión o la falta de información respecto a que JavaScript lo vas a usar del lado del cliente y PHP del lado del servidor(para lo cual necesitas hacer la petición al mismo)

Comment: Ahora bien, lo que mencione anteriormente no solo es para posiblemente ayudarte con una respuesta, sino también para que mejores la calidad de tu pregunta, tal como está solo te llevará a puntuaciones negativas y *(espero que no porque es una pregunta interesante)* a reportes. Ve a [ask] para mas información.

Answer (score 1):

Para ejecutar código de servidor desde un navegador se usa el protocolo http, el código se va a ejecutar siempre que se ejecute el código del navegador, puede ser muchas veces simultáneamente o ninguna, es por ello que no es buena idea como reemplazo de un cron. Si el código de abajo lo abrimos en 5 pestañas van a ejecutarse 5 veces cada minuto.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  fetch('http://example.com/archivo.php')
}, 6000);
```

Si no se espera respuesta, en javaScript se puede usar simplemente `fetch`, en donde realiza una petición http **GET**.